# Office 365 Management Activity API CreationTime no timezone

Tags: office365, office365api

We are using the [Management Activity API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office-365-management-api/office-365-management-activity-api-reference#retrieving-content)  to retrieve activity logs.

We noticed that `CreationTime` field is given as a naive timestamp (unlike for example `contentCreated` field [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office-365-management-api/office-365-management-activity-api-reference#list-available-content), which is given in ISO format).

Does anyone know whether `CreationTime` should be treated as UTC, or is it in the user's timezone (or another option)?

We are processing activity from multiple customers, and we did see that `CreationTime` is pretty much sporadic, compared to time of arrival, but we're not sure whether it's because we assume an incorrect TZ, or is it just how the data is being delivered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CreationTime is the date and time in Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) when the user performed the activity.

Here is the link for your reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office-365-management-api/office-365-management-activity-api-schema

Comment: Thanks, missed that :-)